# jQuery conditional header class swap

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, class

Hope someone can help me out since I don't really know js and would like to build upon an existing function on a WP site...

I have two versions of a site header. On the homepage the alt (transparent background) version loads, and after scrolling, it swaps to the sitewide non-alt (white bg) version.

I would like to add a condition where the header also swaps to the non-alt version when the the menu button is "toggled" (class="main-navigation toggled").

Here's the existing function. Thanks is advance.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.log('ready');
      var header = $(".site-header");
      if( $("body.home").length ) {
        header.addClass("site-header-alt");
      }
        
      $(window).scroll(function() {    
          var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
          
          if( $("body.home").length ) {
            if (scroll <= 100) {
                header.addClass("site-header-alt");
            } else {
                header.removeClass("site-header-alt");
            }
          }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply put:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // check if .main-navigation contains toggled class
    if ( $(".main-navigation").hasClass("toggled") )
    {
        header.addClass("site-header-alt");
    }

    // Also listen to the click event of the element that does the toggling.
    $(".menu-toggle").click( function () {
        if ( $(".main-navigation").hasClass("toggled") )
        {
            header.addClass("site-header-alt");
        }
    });

    // other stuffs
});
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. The element doing the toggling is .menu-toggle. I not sure where to add this in the function. I added it after the scroll function but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I updated my answer, you should put those in your `$(document).ready` function

Comment: Thanks. I actually needed to remove the class, not add it: header.removeClass("site-header-alt");

Comment: Nice, also make sure that mark this as an answer if it solves your problem.